# Cracking sounds made by glowing plankton

Tags: biochemistry

Recently I had opportunity to swim in place with glowing plankton, it was amazing experience and it as well gave birth to few questions in my head.

I manged to google that they can glow thanks to chemical reaction called Bioluminescence.

Once submerged I could hear a cracking sounds, are these sounds as well effect of said chemical reaction?

Few more questions I am wondering:
How often can the plankton light up? Do they need to recharge or something?

Do they light up during the day as well but we can't see them because of daylight or do they act depending on how much light is there around them?